# Serenity + Cucumber + Spring Outputting Byte Code

Tags: spring, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I'm using Serenity and Cucumber with Spring for Dependency Injection support. The test steps are running smoothly and quite fast on IntelIJ (something about 12 minutes).

However, when I run the tests from command line with `mvn clean verify`, the tests run very very very slow and it outputs byte code such as below:

```
16:30:32.419 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "}[0x13][0x98][0x13][0x16]$[0xc][0xf7]z[0x8a][0x19]6F[0x8c][0xc4]U[0x86][0xdc]0+[0xb0][0x1][0xe6](e[0xed][0xc9]9[0xd8][0xba][\r][0xde] [0xa7]U[0x98][0xcb]1[0xc7][0xaf][0xf3]4M8[0xa7][0xc7]_n[0x3]^[0xe7][0x9f]`@[0xd2]WHf*[0xc]8[0xff]U[0x92]!e[0xc1]%[0xb0][0x86][0x1b][0xc0][0xf5]0[0xd6]S[0xf3]m[0xe0]o[0xb6][0x94][0xbd][0x0][0xe2][0x98]~[0xf4]7[0xc][0xb4][0xa5][0xfd][0xdb][0xc7]C[0x92][0xce][0x85]~P[0xa8]W[0xe5][0xf3][0x8a]~[0xf3][0xbf][0xb][0x14][0xdf]2[0xd4]Y[[0x96]A}[0x95][0xfe][0xea][0x9][0x8f][0xfd][0xa5][0xc][0xf1]~[0xb0][0xd1][0xa4][0xe1]F[0x13][0xa6]+[0xf6][0x18][0xca][0xeb][0xfc]~.1[0xd3]*[0x90][0x84][0xd4][0xec][0xc]u$[0xe4]spY[0xcf][0x11][0xc0]e[0xfa][0x2]2[0x9]a2[0x86][0xb1][0x8d][0xf2]P[0xe][0x81][0x18]C[0xa1][0xd0][0x1f][\r][0xd8][0xe3][0x95]5[0xf6][0x0][0xd3]$[0xd6][0x13][0xc1][0x94][0x3]h[0xf5]U[0x12][0xf9][0xa9]#&y[0x9a]8q][0x99][0xb7][0xe2]$[0xd7][0xf1][0x84][0x9d]\[0xfe][0xa2][0xcd]0[0xd4]?^_[0x99][0xc8][0xd1][0xc4]+[0x86][0xb4]L[0x4][0xfb][0x9a][\r][0x8f][0xa0]Dd[0xb2][0x8]8[0x3][0xbb];[0xa2]`[0xec][0xcc][0xfe]u[0x18]>[0xe5][0xea][0xa1][0x5][0xb4][0x11]Urc([0xa5][0xac][0xf0]t[0x18][0xc3]i[0xc][0xa6]v[0x9d]n[0x89][0xb3][0x9c][0x15],y[0xc8][0x15][0xdf][0xf8][0x8a]>[0x13]G[0xaf]N[0xe1]AD<<L[0xcc][0xe5]q[0xd9]T[0xe]a\[0xf1][0x19][0xdb][0x1f]w[0x4][0xd3][0xf0][0xa8][0x88][0xfd]P[0xda][0xf][0x90][0xd4]y[0xea][0x87][0xf8][0xaa]_[0xa2]J[0x6][0x93]R[0xb6][0x8d]x{~f#=[0x93][0xf0][0xe4][0xc3]X[0x19][0xde][0x96]E[0x1a][0xfa][0x0]+[0x4][0xe8][0x3][0x11][\n]"
```

Has anyone ever encountered similar behaviour? If so, what can be done about this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check if you've got debug logging on somewhere when running with maven. The sheer amount of information logged at debug level will slow down your machine.

Answer (score 1):

> Check if you've got debug logging on somewhere when running with maven. The sheer amount of information logged at debug level will slow down your machine

The comment by @mrkorstanje is the solution. I managed to disable Spring loggings and the tests run as expected now.